# string operation in .net during file i/o - before it was tab now it is §

Tags: .net, file, tabs, io

In my current code, I am using this code for files which have delimiter tab so I use '\t' in code
Now delimiter changed to § instead of tab so what ASCII escape sequence should be used.

## Current code:

```
string[] strFields = inputRecord.Split('\t');
```

## New code:

```
string[] strFields = inputRecord.Split('***'); what *** should be?
```

I tried with § but does not work

Comment: What happens when you use '§' then? No need for an escape sequence.

Comment: How d you open the file and read from it? Can you post that code? Also, can you try reading the file as raw bytes to see what the actual byte values are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably read the file in the wrong encoding. Try a different encoding:

```
new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in the unicode character escape code instead?

```
string[] strFields = inputRecord.Split('\u00A7');
```

Though, using the `§` straight in the text worked for me:

```
string[] strFields = inputRecord.Split('§');
```

Are you sure that you used the correct unicode character?  Since .NET strings are unicode, are you sure that the character is being mapped to that unicode character?  It could be a difference in something like a codepage, if your source string was ansi, for example.

EDIT: I would try Mark's suggestion, it probably is a codepage problem, and I suspect his solution would work.